# How to extract value from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

How can I extract the last value, 102.584855? I have tried `df[-1:].iloc[0]` but it will return the 20 as well. Howe to get only 102.58485? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use: `df.iloc[-1, 0]`. [When 2 indexers are passed to `iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#selection-by-position), the first indicates the index of the rows, the second the index of the columns. So `df.iloc[-1, 0]` selects the value in the last row and first column.

Alternatively, [`df[-1:].iloc[0].item()` would also work](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html), but is less efficient.